# How to obtain the analytical solution for $x(t)$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> $\dot x = 1-2\cos(x)$
>
> I know the answer which is: $$x = 2\arctan\frac{i}{\sqrt3}\tan\left(\frac{\sqrt3i}{2}(t+C)\right)$$

but I dont know how one could get such answer.

My try so far is to set up equations like: $$\int dt = \int \frac{1}{1-2\cos(x)}dx$$ and by wolfram i get, $$t + C = \frac{-2\arctan(\sqrt3\tan(\frac{x}{2}))}{\sqrt3} + C$$ but then where does $i$ come from?

Also, with the solution above, the answer sheet also provides $$C(t=0) = \frac{2}{\sqrt3i}\arctan(\frac{\sqrt3}{i}\tan(\frac{x}{2}))$$ but I'm not sure what kind of meaning this solution has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wolfram Alpha's solution of your integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+1%2F(1-2+cos(x)%29) is
$$
\frac{-2\tanh^{-1}(\sqrt3\tan(x/2))}{\sqrt3} + \text{constant}.
$$

The function $\tanh^{-1}$ is not the same as $\arctan$.
Note the letter "h" in $\tanh$, which indicates that this is the
*hyperbolic* tangent function.

Also note that
$$
\tanh^{-1} x = \frac1i \arctan(ix)
$$
(based on formula $(2)$ from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseHyperbolicTangent.html).
So that's where the $i$s come from.

Answer (score 0):

You have several strategies to integrate fractions of trigonometric expressions. One is to convert to complex numbers via
$$
z=e^{ix},\quad \cos x=\frac12(z+z^{-1})
$$
and find an anti-derivative via partial fraction decomposition as usual.

One other is via the half-angle tangent, $t=\tan\frac x2$ where
$$
\cos x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\quad \sin x=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}
$$
and again continue via partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 0):

$$x'(t)=1-2\cos\left(x(t)\right)\Longleftrightarrow\int\frac{x'(t)}{1-2\cos\left(x(t)\right)}\space\text{d}t=\int1\space\text{d}t$$

Now, use:

1. Substitute $u=x(t)$ and $\text{d}u=x'(t)\space\text{d}t$:
   $$\int\frac{x'(t)}{1-2\cos\left(x(t)\right)}\space\text{d}t=\int\frac{1}{1-2\cos\left(u\right)}\space\text{d}u=-\frac{\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{3}\cdot\tan\left(\frac{x(t)}{2}\right)+1}{\sqrt{3}\cdot\tan\left(\frac{x(t)}{2}\right)-1}\right|}{\sqrt{3}}+\text{C}$$
2. $$\int1\space\text{d}t=t+\text{C}$$

So, we get:

$$-\frac{\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{3}\cdot\tan\left(\frac{x(t)}{2}\right)+1}{\sqrt{3}\cdot\tan\left(\frac{x(t)}{2}\right)-1}\right|}{\sqrt{3}}=t+\text{C}$$